# Show descriptions for model properties which are custom types using Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have this model:

```cs
public class Order {

  /// <summary>
  /// The customer.
  /// </summary>
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}

public class Customer {

  /// <summary>
  /// This is not shown.                 <---
  /// </summary>
  public int Id { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// This is not shown.                 <---
  /// </summary>
  public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The `Customer` class is defined in a separate assembly.

The swagger ui does not show descriptions for the `Customer` model's `Id` and `Name` properties.

I tried [these](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1915) [options](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#inheritance-and-polymorphism), which didn't help:

```cs
options.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
options.UseAllOfForInheritance();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi @lonix, Which version of Swashbuckle you are using? For the nested Models missing descriptions, it seems that it is a known issue, and it has fixed in the latest version (v6 version), you could try to use it. Reference: [Nested Models Missing Descriptions](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1441) and [<summary> xml annotation not working for properties in nested objects](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/86).

Comment: @ZhiLv Thanks! That lead me to the solution, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All XML files must be included, not just the one for the entry assembly.

```cs
var dir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
var paths = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (var path in paths) o.IncludeXmlComments(path);
```